# Error when trying to find Ribbon Control Resource Dictionary - Office2007Blue

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I keep getting an error #6 (An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml") when I try an load the Office2007Blue resource dictionary that is supposed to come with the WPF RibbonControlLibrary.  Has anyone seen this problem and found a fix?  I'm using version 3.5.40729.1 of this control.

My XAML is as follows and I've located it within Application.xaml;

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna,
                                         Version=3.0.0.0,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
                                         ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/luna.metallic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml"  />                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- other resources go here -->

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, these aren't included with the version put out by the WPF team.  :(